# Swift - add .scn to sprite view

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a `.scn` file to my sprite view but am getting this error: `-[SCNScene removeFromParent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000628d80`. How can I add a `.scn` file to my `spriteview` ?

```
var body: some View {
      ZStack {
          SpriteView(scene: spriteScene)
      }
   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}

lazy var spriteScene: SKScene = {
    let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "rocketSpriteView")!
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene.addChild(particleEmitter!)
    scene.addChild(rocketSprite!)
    return scene
}()

var particleEmitter: SKEmitterNode? {
    return SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Particle.sks")
}

var rocketSprite: SKNode? {
    let node = SKNode(fileNamed: "rocket.scn")
    node?.removeFromParent()
    return node
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.scn` files are SceneKit Scenes files, you can't load directly on `SKNode`.

You could load the scene file on a SCNScene with:

```swift
let scene: SCNScene? = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/rocket.scn")
```

Then you can access to the root node with:

```swift
let node: SCNNode = scene.rootNode
```